# Is it possible to control the sliders in animation programmatically?

Tags: animation

Does *Mathematica* have the functionality to control the sliders in animation? That is, run sliders when some condition, like an if condition is fulfilled.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3):

Both `Animator` and `Animate`, as well as other forms of animators, allow a `Dynamic` setting to the `AnimationRunning` option.  We use a variable as a flag to signal whether to run or stop the animation.

In either

```
$runQ = False;                                                         (* SE $ bug fix *)
Animator[Dynamic[murf], AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[$runQ]]
```

or

```
$runQ = False;                                                         (* SE $ bug fix *)
Animate[Plot[Sin[10 Pi Cos[2 Pi a] t], {t, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> 1.01],
 {a, 0, 1},
 AnimationRunning -> Dynamic[$runQ]]
```

setting

```
$runQ = True
```

turns on the animation, if it's off; and setting

```
$runQ = False
```

turns it off, it it's on.  These also work with the run/pause button, which gets passed `Dynamic[$runQ]`; indeed, pressing the button will change the value of `$runQ`.